# Unable to find functions for a cython build through C language

Tags: c, cython

I have a Cython project with the following modules:

CythonModule.pyx:

```
cdef int CPyFuncSwo():
    print("Do some stuff in cython")
    return 0

cdef public void PyFuncSwo()
    CPyFuncSwo()
    print("Do some stuff but in pure python only")
```

CythonModule.pxd:

```
cdef int CPyFuncSwo()
```

Setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "CythonModule",
        sources=["CythonModule.pyx",],
    ),
]

setup(
    name="CythonModule",
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
    compiler_directives={'language_level': 3, "unraisable_tracebacks": True}
)
```

run.py:

```
import os
import sys
from CythonModule import PyFuncSwo
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("."))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PyFuncSwo()
```

This works perfectly fine and when I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace && python run.py`, the code compiles and runs while also giving me a new `CythonModule.cp39-win_amd64.pyd` file. Now I need to call `PyFuncSwo()` from the .pyd module in a pure C/C++ code. Surfing through the web, I came across the following example:

RunCythonInC.c:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef (add_proc)(int a, int b);
int main(){
    add_proc *add;
    HANDLE h_dll;
    int a = 1, b = 2, c;
    h_dll = LoadLibrary("CythonModule.cp39-win_amd64.pyd");
    if(h_dll)
      {
        add = GetProcAddress(h_dll, "PyFuncSwo");
        if(add)
        {
          c = add(a, b); /*Explicit Call*/
        }
        else
        {
          printf("PyFuncSwo not found in CythonModule.cp39-win_amd64.pyd");
        }
        FreeLibrary(h_dll);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("Unable to load CythonModule.cp39-win_amd64.pyd");
        exit(-1);
      }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code with gcc as `gcc -g RunCythonInC.c -o RunCythonInC.exe` compiles with the following warnings, but when I run RunCythonInC.exe, I always get `PyFuncSwo not found in CythonModule.cp39-win_amd64.pyd`.

I also changed `GetProcAddress(h_dll, "PyFuncSwo")` to `GetProcAddress(h_dll, "CPyFuncSwo")` but am I still getting the same error. Other things I tried was calling cython functions with an _ as `GetProcAddress(h_dll, "_PyFuncSwo")` but still got the same result. Can anyone tell me, how do I call my cython functions from the .pyd module in a pure C code?

**Update:**

As per the Cython's documentation [Here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c), it seems that the proper way to declare cython functions in C is to define the cython function type as public and build it. This will generate a "CythonModule.h" header file, which can be included in your C code and then can call the cython functions.

following this instruction, I came up with the following C code:

run.c:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include "CythonModule.h"

int main(){
    PyImport_AppendInittab("PyFuncSwo", PyInit_CythonModule);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyImport_ImportModule("PyFuncSwo");
    return 0;
}
```

and changed `def PyFuncSwo()` to `cdef public void PyFuncSwo()`.

Now I get the following errors:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaMLv6A.o:run.c:(.rdata$.refptr.PyInit_CythonModule[.refptr.PyInit_CythonModule]+0x0): undefined reference to `PyInit_CythonModule'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

CythonModule.h:

```
/* Generated by Cython 0.29.23 */

#ifndef __PYX_HAVE__CythonModule
#define __PYX_HAVE__CythonModule

#include "Python.h"

#ifndef __PYX_HAVE_API__CythonModule

#ifndef __PYX_EXTERN_C
  #ifdef __cplusplus
    #define __PYX_EXTERN_C extern "C"
  #else
    #define __PYX_EXTERN_C extern
  #endif
#endif

#ifndef DL_IMPORT
  #define DL_IMPORT(_T) _T
#endif

__PYX_EXTERN_C void __pyx_f_13CythonModule_PyFuncSwo(void);

#endif /* !__PYX_HAVE_API__CythonModule */

/* WARNING: the interface of the module init function changed in CPython 3.5. */
/* It now returns a PyModuleDef instance instead of a PyModule instance. */

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
PyMODINIT_FUNC initCythonModule(void);
#else
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_CythonModule(void);
#endif

#endif /* !__PYX_HAVE__CythonModule */
```

Comment: Do not tag C++ for C questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is symbol visibility. The functions need to be `cdef public` and possibly [need manually exporting on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025026).

### However

**What you're trying to do is wrong** and is unlikely to work.

Cython does not create standalone C functions. Instead it generates Python modules. Cython functions have two important prerequisites:

1. The Python interpreter is running.
2. The module import function for the Cython module *must* have been called.

If these prerequisites aren't met the functions are likely to crash in unexpected and confusing ways.

The correct way of calling Cython functions from C [is covered in the Cython documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c) and does not involve `GetProcAddress`.

### Edit: Full example

I kept your CythonModule.pyx and CythonModule.pxd almost as is (I had to add a colon to the line `cdef public void PyFuncSwo()`.

I compiled those to C with `cython CythonModule.pyx`.

I modified run.c slightly to remove windows.h since I'm not using Windows and to add `PyFuncSwo()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include "CythonModule.h"

int main(){
    PyImport_AppendInittab("PyFuncSwo", PyInit_CythonModule);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyImport_ImportModule("PyFuncSwo");
    PyFuncSwo();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I use `PyFuncSwo()` - the mangled version of the name is different on earlier Cython versions but is fixed in both the Cython 3 pre-release and the `0.29.33`.

I compile this with `gcc` python3-config --cflags --ldflags --embed `CythonModule.c run.c -o prog` (Note on Linux, not Windows)

and running `prog` gives the output

```
Do some stuff in cython
Do some stuff but in pure python only
```

(although in reality the output is wrong - both print statements execute in Cython-compiled code).

Comment: appologies for late response, but I tried your suggestion and followed the documentation, but I am still having a differnt issue, can you please look at the question "Update" section?

Comment: You need to make sure that you're compiling "Cython module.c" so an .o file and linking that with your main program

Comment: DavidW, would be able to provide an example of run.c code calling `PyFuncSwo` from my cythonmodule.pyd for a python3.9? I was able to successfully link CythonModule.c to run.c but executing run.exe doesn't call the `PyFuncSwo` function. my gcc params: `gcc -o run.exe run.c CythonModule.c -IC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\username\A
ppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -LC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs -lpython39`

Comment: I think you just need to call `__pyx_f_13CythonModule_PyFuncSwo` after the module import. (Cython has managed the name a little, which is a bug that I think is fixed in the 3.0 beta version). Don't have time to test it right now I'm afraid but will be able to look in a few days

Comment: I tried calling `__pyx_f_13CythonModule_PyFuncSwo`, but still nothing happened, would really appreciate if you test it any time you get a change

Comment: See the edit - it works for me as described

Comment: ufff, in windows when I call `PyFuncSwo()` after `PyImport_importModule("PyFuncSwo")`, it says undefined reference: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\cchNT6Gi.o:run.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference
to `PyFuncSwo'` Also, I don't have `python3-config  --cflags --ldflags --embed` in windows gcc. My cython version is `0.29.34`

Comment: It seems that they still havent fixed the naming convention in windows, I called `__pyx_f_13commonmodules_mainCode` after import module, and it worked :) Thank you very much David for the help. Really appreciate it

Comment: Hey @DavidW, would you know the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76088082/nameerror-name-ctypes-is-not-defined-cython-declaration-in-c ? I am facing another problem and am unable to find it in cython documentation