# NameError: name 'ctypes' is not defined, cython declaration in C

Tags: c, cython

I have cython module as below:

cmmodule.pyx:

```
import ctypes
import os
#... other imports

cdef int doStuff():
    print("Do some stuff as administrator")
    return 0

cdef public void mainCode():
    print("I am doing stuff here")
    if ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
        if (not os.path.isdir("deco")):
            os.mkdir("capture")

        doStuff()
    else:
        hinstance = ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(
            None, 'runas', sys.executable, sys.argv[0], None, SW.SHOWNORMAL
        )
        if hinstance <= 32:
            raise RuntimeError(ERROR(hinstance))
```

cmmodule.pxd:

```
cdef int doStuff()
cdef public void mainCode()
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "cmmodule",
        sources=["cmmodule.pyx",],
    ),
]

setup(
    name="appname",
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
    compiler_directives={'language_level': 3, "unraisable_tracebacks": True}
)
```

I then build this module using setup.py as `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.

Now I would like to access and run my cython declarations `mainCode` in pure C.

run.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include "cmmodule.h"

int main(){
    PyImport_AppendInittab("mainCode", PyInit_cmmodule);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyImport_ImportModule("mainCode");
    __pyx_f_13cmmodule_mainCode();
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile my run.c code as `gcc -o run.exe run.c cmmodule.c -IC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\username\A ppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -LC:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs -lpython39`

This compiles just fine, but when I run it, I get the following output:

**Problem**

```
I am doing stuff here
NameError: name 'ctypes' is not defined
Exception ignored in: 'commonmodules.mainCode'
NameError: name 'ctypes' is not defined
```

As you can see in the output, my `mainCode` function has been called and it ran the `print("I am doing stuff here")` but then it failed to import the `ctypes` module from python.

**Question**

Can anyone tell me, what am I doing wrong here? or what is the proper way to import python modules that are accessible in C?

I tried to move `import ctypes` inside my mainCode function as below, which then I got my print output first then the code crashes without any errors, it also doesn't execute `ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()` line. I am assuming that since the code cannot import `ctypes` the program just crashes.

```
cdef public void mainCode():
    print("Running MainCode() here")
    import ctypes
    if ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():

    ...
```

Comment: A couple of quick pointers: 1) `PyImport_ImportModule` returns `NULL` if it fails, so it's worth checking that. 2) The main issue will be to do Python's search path, which isn't set by default in embedded Python. Use `PySys_SetPath` to set that.

Comment: @DavidW, is it possible make the run.exe standalone, so that when compiled by GCC, it should not require any python header files?

Comment: Also, as you suggested, I checked if `PyImport_importModule` fails to load mainCode and it indeed does fail:` if(PyImport_ImportModule("mainCode") == NULL){
        printf("Failed to import mainCode\n");
    }`

Comment: adding `PySys_SetPath("C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/python39");` after `Py_Initialize()`, I now get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz'`. xyz.pyx is another module that is used in my cmmodules.pyx. In other words I have `cimport xyz` in my cmmodules.pyx

Comment: You probably want `"C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/python39;."` - the `.` adds the current directory.

Comment: "1is it possible make the run.exe standalone, so that when compiled by GCC, it should not require any python header files"- **No**. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59389683/4657412. Cython is not the solution for this. Don't waste your time trying

Comment: I added '.' to the path, but am still getting the same error as xyz.pyx module is not found

Comment: Also, when I compile my run.exe I run `gcc run.c cmmodule.c xyz.c ...`

Comment: @DavidW, would you have any other suggestiongs? setting . and python path using `PySys_SetPath` didnt work :(